# Como criar looping para somar elementos do mesmo vetor e printar os resultados parciais?

Tags: r, loop, for

criei uma sequência de elementos e preciso agora fazer a soma entre eles, onde cada interação deve imprimir a soma atual, qual o número a ser somado e o resultado da soma.

Criei primeiro a sequência:

```
minha_sequencia = seq(from=1, to= 100, by = 7)

#[1]  1  8 15 22 29 36 43 50 57 64 71 78 85 92 99
```

Agora estou tentado criar o looping, mas só consigo a soma total dos elementos, e não como pedido no exercício.

```
for (linha in 1:nrow(minha_sequencia)){
    print(sum(minha_sequencia))
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 6):

Imagino que esteja fazendo um exercício. Mas para ficar registrado, o que está buscando obter é a soma cumulativa. R tem a função primitiva `cumsum` para isso:

```
minha_sequencia = seq(1, 100, by = 7)

cumsum(minha_sequencia)
#> [1]   1   9  24  46  75 111 154 204 261 325 396 474 559 651 750
```

Comment: Bem notado, Carlos

Comment: Isso mesmo, Carlos! Acredito que o intuito era exercitar a função looping, mas a sua sugestão é muito mais eficiente. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

O "erro" no seu código é que você não está usando a variável que é gerada no loop para somar. Além disso eu criei uma variável para exibir os resultados parciais. Veja:

```
minha_sequencia = seq(from=1, to= 100, by = 7)
resultado_parcial = 0

for (linha in minha_sequencia){
    resultado_parcial = resultado_parcial + linha
    print( resultado_parcial )
}
```

Repare que se você usar `sum(minha_sequencia)` só vai mostrar a soma de todos os numeros repetidamente até que o loop chegue ao fim.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é usar um índice para selecionar apenas os `n` primeiros elementos do vetor a cada interação do `for`.

```r
minha_sequencia = seq(from=1, to= 100, by = 7)

for (linha in seq_along(minha_sequencia)){
  print(sum(minha_sequencia[1:linha]))
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 9
#> [1] 24
#> [1] 46
#> [1] 75
#> [1] 111
#> [1] 154
#> [1] 204
#> [1] 261
#> [1] 325
#> [1] 396
#> [1] 474
#> [1] 559
#> [1] 651
#> [1] 750
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Excelente! muito obrigado